# Shared Library Installation

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries, static-libraries, dynamic-linking

I need to install a shared library in the location other than the standard location(/usr/lib) in Ubuntu 16.04. I have read [this article](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html). But I can't able to understand it clearly. Could anyone please explain how we can actually install and use a shared library in simple terms, so a beginner can understand. 
And also what mean by this error message:

"./executable: error while loading shared libraries: maths.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

I often get this message while running programs that use shared libraries.Please let me know if you need any further information.

Thanks

PreeJackie

Comment: What do you mean by installing shared libraries, is it part of some package. you can extract the package to any custom location too.

Comment: I'm creating a shared library from the two object code files. After the creation, we need to install it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming foo.c your source file example.so is the shared library at /home/lib location

```
gcc -o foo foo.c -L/home/lib -lexample -Wl,-rpath=/home/lib
```

foo.c - your c file.
example.so - your custom shared library.

```
gcc -o output_file input_file -L<shard library path> -l<library name without .so>  -Wl,-rpath=<shared library path>
```

Comment: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lexample 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: How to correct this? The "shared lib path" -> /home/praveen/libs

Comment: where is your shared library ? Is it at  "home/praveen/libs"?. do ls  on  "/home/praveen/libs"

Comment: and what is your library name, Can you show us the exact command and library name you used?

Comment: gcc -o res demo.o -L/home/praveen/libs -lslib -Wl,-rpath=/home/praveen/libs

Comment: library name is slib

Comment: Could you please also explain the command, so that I can know how it's working :)

Comment: your shard library name should have extension .so. 
gcc -o res demo.c  -L/home/praveen/libs -lslib -Wl,-rpath=/home/praveen/libs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174752/discussion-between-preejackie-and-user2760375).